# Facebook Location section of "Preferred Page Audience" never loads

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am having facebook page [Java By Patel](https://www.facebook.com/javabypatel) and was able to edit "Preferred Page Audience  -->  Location" 5 days back.

But from last 5 days I am not able to edit it and Location section of "Preferred Page Audience" never loads. is there any solution to this??

I tried accessing by changing browser but no help.

[image: Location never loads]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is still an issue?

Comment: I just checked. Yes. Issue still persist.